# Why doesn't the creation of a new String use intern() by default?

Tags: java, string

I have read about intern() and almost everywhere it is written that it will speed up string comparison by using == instead of equals().

```
String a = new String("1");
String b = new String("1");
```

If I am right, the code above will create 2 strings in string pool. But after reading about intern, I don't see a reason to save 2 strings with the same value in the pool.

**So the question is:** why doesn't java use intern() by default?

If possible I would like to get a detailed explanation.

Comment: `new` creates a new object (by calling the constructor) and returns its reference. You are creating a different object each time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> If I am right, code above will create 2 strings in string pool.

Not in the string pool, no. That produces *one* string in the string pool (because of the string constant `"1"`) and two strings elsewhere in memory (because of the two calls to `new String`).

> why java doesn't use intern by default?

Because there's no need to do it by default. Interning a string requires work (finding the existing entry if any, adding it if not there). If the strings are transient (as many are), that's unnecessary work. Thus, leave it to the programmer, who will call `intern` if appropriate.

---

> ...almoust everywhere written that it will speed up string comparition by using == instead equals()

I have no idea where this "almost everywhere" is, but using `==` to compare strings is just plain wrong in Java. `==` compares object references. While it's true (I think) that if you interned each and every string and never once forgot, then `==` would be reliable (I *think*), it's not best practice at all. Use `equals`. That's what it's for. :-) It will, after all, start by doing `==` to see if the two strings being compared are the same object, and only if that's false go on to compare the actual characters...

---

Just a side note: There's almost never any reason to explicitly call `new String(String)` (there are *other* overloads of the constructor that are definitely useful, for instance when you need to convert an array of bytes into a string using a particular charset).

Comment: It's convenient to call `String` constructors when finding a `String` from a a code point sequence or via a character set decoding. Also, some implementations used/use a shared backing array with the `String(String)` constructor providing a to decouple from an overlong `char[]`.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline - I think something went wrong in your final sentence there...?

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline - I should have said no reason to call `new String(String)` since, as you point out, there are other overloads which are definitely useful.

Comment: Thank you for answer.  You said "While it's true (I think) that if you interned each and every string and never once forgot, then == would be reliable (I think), it's not best practice at all", and I thought if java would always by default use intern on every string, then there is no need to check by equals

Comment: @airush - The problem is the extra work. You don't want your basic language features (like strings) jumping through unnecessary hoops. (The question of whether there was a better answer than the `equals` method is a separate matter. :-) [IMHO, there was, but not by interning strings.])

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you once more. I should read more about Java Heap and String Pool. I thought I know about String pool (: naive

Comment: @airush - We all are. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Sorry I promise this is the last question :)  I am reading about string and still can't get why we need 2 strings in memory "and two strings elsewhere in memory" if we could use one from string pool?

Comment: @airush - `new String` **always** creates a new object, it never uses the string from the pool. So when your class is loaded, the string for the literal `"1"` is created and interned; that string is in the string pool (more accurately: it's in memory somewhere, and *referenced* from the string pool). Then your code calls `new String` twice, so it creates two new string objects, also in memory somewhere. Thus, three strings, since the two you created aren't interned.